# Will Windows give me problems if I upgrade my processor?

Tags: windows-7, cpu

Assuming the motherboard and BIOS will support it, can I change from a dual core processor to a quad core without Windows 7 giving me any grief?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can. As you say "Assuming the motherboard and bios are all ready to go" if this condition is OK, I mean, if your processor uses the same socket and a compatible chipset you could not only upgrade from a dual core to quad core but the other way as well, downgrading from quad core to a dual core processor.

Answer (score 21):

Both dual core and quad core systems would very likely use the same SMP kernel, and be unlikely to give you trouble due to that. If you wish to play it safe, you may want to run [sysprep](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) /generalize to make it a generic, non specialized system before you do the processor swap.

Other issues such as activation may still need to be taken care of, but this should allow the system to be bootable without driver incompatibilities.

Comment: i like this answer

Comment: sysprep is always a good idea, can save a lot of grief.

Comment: Are you sure you want to run `sysprep` for a CPU change? This sounds like a horrible idea based on the documentation. I was under the assumption that having your SID reset is usually not desirable.

Comment: I wasn't aware of any world shaking risks - OTOH, it seems sysprep isn't for windows 7. I'll have to look at doing some tests and updating my answer once these are done.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Actually [it turns out](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/11/03/3291024.aspx) that machine SIDs are never exposed to the outside world on client computers; it's apparently totally okay to never change them. You still need unique machine SIDs on your domain controllers because that gets promoted to the domain SID, and the client's domain SID needs to be unique (e.g by having the clone re-join the domain), but the client's machine SID isn't ever exposed to the network. That's why SysInternals retired NewSID.

Answer (score 4):

For a cpu change there should be no problem, since there aren't any drivers involved (which Windows 7 would get from the internet anyway).
Maybe it will ask you to re-activate... but that depends on what has changed, not only now but in the past since your last activation.